# kill unicorn process on deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, unicorn

I'm trying to add unicorn to my app, in my deploy script I have this lines added:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    run "if [ -f #{unicorn_pid} ] && [ -e /proc/$(cat #{unicorn_pid}) ]; then kill -0 `cat #{unicorn_pid}`; else cd #{deploy_to}/current && bundle exec unicorn_rails -c #{unicorn_conf} -E #{rails_env} -D; fi"
  end
  task :start do
    run "bundle exec unicorn_rails -c #{unicorn_conf} -E #{rails_env} -D"
  end
  task :stop do
    run "if [ -f #{unicorn_pid} ] && [ -e /proc/$(cat #{unicorn_pid}) ]; then kill -QUIT `cat #{unicorn_pid}`; fi"
  end

  task :load_rvm do
    run '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
  end
end
```

but when I run the deploy script I have this error on task "restart":

```
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

Answer (score 0):

Kill command won't take **-0** option. That must be **-9**